# Math Educators Stackexchange is live!

Tags: discussion, math-educators-se

The new site http://matheducators.stackexchange.com is now up and running! This site is for questions about course-design, exam-writing, teaching methods, intuition and examples, etc.

Check out our top questions list:

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

Please consider contributing! This site is still in it's infancy, and would benefit greatly from your help.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: (I'm not sure a tag is needed for this, by the way.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila what about that one [meta-tag:math-stackexchange] and its synonym even [meta-tag:math-se] ;-)

Comment: @quid: If the website's interaction with MO is expected to generate more than a handful of meta threads, sure. But is it the case here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila if it should survive at all I do not see why it would not (at least if 8 is more than a handful); the idea is another site for professional mathematicians. In some sense its target audience is closer to MO's than that of math.SE is. As Bohr said, it is difficult to make predictions, especially if they concern the future. and the tag is gone...so let us see.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to all the people who have put so much time and hard work into making this site.

Great job and thank you!