# Should this teaching question about Graph Theory be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Should [What (fun) results in graph theory should undergraduates learn?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230366/what-fun-results-in-graph-theory-should-undergraduates-learn) be reopened?  In the comments, Andrej Bauer suggests that it is should be moved to Math Educators Stack Exchange, while Fedor Petrov thinks it is on-topic here.  Personally, I voted to reopen, since the question provides some context (location=UK, level=3rd year), and how it differs from the similar teaching question [Interesting and Accessible Topics in Graph Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64448/interesting-and-accessible-topics-in-graph-theory) (which was not closed). I also agree with Fedor Petrov that a teaching question should not automatically be closed for not being research level.  Otherwise, why do we even have a teaching tag?  Admittedly, this question is a bit soft (even for a teaching question), but not worthy of deletion in my opinion.

Comment: Related, near duplicate http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2155/how-should-we-react-to-the-existence-of-math-educators-se

Comment: Thanks for raising this - it was my question Tony Huynh refers to. I have no problem with the question being closed (whatever that means) if it's off-topic. Any suggestions on how to make it more relevant would be appreciated? In view of the similar 'good' question Tony and I both mentioned, it's not clear to me how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps it is a better fit for [matheducators.se]?